# Is there a standard function for "do this if Just x"?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
doIf :: (a -> IO ()) -> Maybe a -> IO ()
doIf f x = case x of
  Just i -> f i
  Nothing -> return ()

main = do
  mapM_ (doIf print) [Just 3, Nothing, Just 4]
```

which outputs:

```
3
4
```

In other words, the `Just` values are printed, but `Nothing` values cause no action.  (And do not interrupt computation.)

Is there a standard function like this in the Haskell libraries?  Also, can this be made more generic?  I tried replacing `IO ()` with `m b` but then `return ()` does not work.  How do you generically write `return ()` for any monad? (If possible..)  Can even the `Maybe` be generalized here?

Lastly, can I do away with the `doIf` function entirely?  Can I have an operator <#> that applies an argument unless `Nothing`?

```
print <#> Just 3
print <#> Nothing
```

would output

```
3
```

But I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess it's sort of a monadic "with".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `doIf` is a special case of [`Data.Foldable.traverse_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_).

You can usually find this sort of thing through [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(a+-%3E+IO+())+-%3E+Maybe+a+-%3E+IO+()), but it seems to be a little broken at the moment.  The command-line version I have installed on my system gives `Data.Foldable.traverse_` as the first result for the query `(a -> IO ()) -> Maybe a -> IO ()`.

---

And sure, you can define that operator, it's just `(<#>) = doIf` (or `(<#>) = Data.Foldable.traverse_`).

Comment: Thanks, wow "traverse" is not the name I would have thought of for that function.

Comment: It makes more sense for other instances of Foldable/Traversable such as arrays.  You can think of a Maybe value as a list of length at most one, in which case your function "traverses" that list.

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at the function:

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

You've almost written it in `doIf` except for the fixed `return ()`

Comment: Aha, thanks! Somehow I was thinking about monadic code and didn't consider looking at functions that didn't have some kind of "m b" signature.

Comment: Yes, and `IO ()` is just another type, can be `b` here.

Answer (score 5):

Could you do somthing along the lines of:

```
main = do
  mapM_ print $ catMaybes [Just 3, Nothing, Just 4]
```

See the documentation for [catMaybes](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes).

*(NB: Untested code)*

Comment: I like this approach. Dividing the problem up into smaller problems, and staying away from IO longer.